# Conjunctions of disjunction in java

Tags: java

Is there any way in java to get conjunctions of disjunctions of strings, i.e, for example

If I have two String str1="a" and str2="c or d", where "or" here is disjunction. I need to get the output of conjunction of these two strings, i.e, a and (c or d) = (a and c) or (a and d)

Is this possible in java ?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve and why do you want to do it with `String`s?

Comment: Just to make sure I've understood your question - you want some kind of boolean calculator?

Comment: Of course it's possible.  But I don't think there's a built-in method in the JRE that does this for you.  There may be other libraries to analyze and process Boolean mathematical expressions, but StackOverflow isn't set up to ask about recommended tools or libraries, and answers about how you would write something yourself (other than in very simple cases like your example) would be way too complicated for this site.

Comment: @mystarrocks; @Doe Johnson: Yes. Exactly. I am trying to implement boolean calculator.

Comment: @ajb: yes, I can understand. But I am not getting any clue how to implement. Just thought if I would get any suggestions on how to implement this or any related code snippet, it would be helpful.

Comment: I don't know the extend of your ambitions. I mean you can simply build some kind of parser that converts given input to a boolean expression but you would need to define if a certain String is true or false. Otherwise it wouldn't make any sense.